# Display output of a job in Jenkins

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I am using Jenkins to run a simple script which displays output on the console. Now what I want is the output of the job is displayed on Jenkins dashboard somewhere.

Let us say the build script just does a `dir`. Now I want to be able to click on the latest build of the project and see the output in Jenkins. I know I can always click on the build and then `"console output"`. But this gives me more info than required, meaning it also gives me the inner workings of the script. What I want is a **"dumb-user"** display which just gives me the final output of the script.

Any plug-ins or ways to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output the results to a file in the target then you can click on the workspace link to view the file. You could also set a Post-build action to archive the file as an artifact and then it will show up on the main Jenkins page for the project.

Comment: Many thanks. I already hit upon the workspace one but was not even aware of the post-build step. Suits my purpose well. Cheers mate :)